# SIMBL/Bundle/dylib injection into Dock.app

Tags: macos, code-injection, dock, simbl

I'm working on a simple SIMBL bundle to decrease the FullScreen animation time in Lion. It's no big deal to change the animation of the windows, however doing that for the menubar/desktop animation part (where the menubar+desktop slide to the left) is a problem. 
I think that Dock.app is responsible for that animation.
However, SIMBL can't inject a bundle into Dock.app (same with Finder).

I tried creating a .dylib which then would be loaded into Dock by setting the LSEnvironment in Dock's Info.plist but that failed.

Is there any good way to inject a bundle/dylib into Dock.app?
Thanks in Advance

PS: Dock is root:wheel :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I only need x64 injection (Lion) I ended up using this https://github.com/StarProject/StarRuntime
It's way easier to use than mach_inject or similar and GPL.

Comment: How did you use StarRuntime? Can you share some details?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject in Dock & Finder with SIMBL. SIMBL works for cocoa applications only!
You have to write your own injection system something like this, http://scplugin.tigris.org/svn/scplugin/trunk/ (username:guest, password:guest) or Look for Application Enhancer.

Answer (score 2):

you can also check [inject&interpose](https://github.com/comex/inject_and_interpose)

Comment: it's been some while since I checked back. thanks for that suggestion